# Relative speed of minute hand in a clock

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

In a 12 hours clock:

```
The minute hand has to chase the hour hand with a relative speed of 5.5 degrees/min
```

what is the mathematical derivation of this relative speed?

Answer (score 3):

The hour hand rotates at $0.5$ degrees per minute and the minute hand rotates at $6$ degrees per minute...